# Improving a question closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion

I have a [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323029/metadata-on-the-wp-post-object) which was closed as a duplicate.

As I see it, the accepted duplicated asks the *how*, whereas my question is about the *why*. I've tried to improve the question a bit. Is it still a duplicate?

Comment: "why" is usually off topic on StackExchange sites as it is too opinionated

Comment: Uhm, no, _why_ is kinda the essential question in every situation. :) I have reopened the question after your edits.